# Inverse selection in ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

**What I Have**

I have a ListView which Contextual Action Bar. In the CAB, I have an option "Select All" which selects all the items in the list. It works perfectly.

**What I Want**

I want to put an option to inverse the selection. Like, suppose there are 10 items in a list and the user selects the first two and chooses the "Inverse" option, then the rest of the 8 items will be selected.

Example - This option can be found in popular file managers like Solid Explorer.

**What I Have Done**

```
public class FileBrowserAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        List<FileItem> list = Collections.emptyList();
        List<FileItem> mStringFilterList = Collections.emptyList();
        ValueFilter valueFilter;

        private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

        public FileBrowserAdapter(Context context, List<FileItem> list) {

            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.list = list;
            this.context = context;
            mStringFilterList = list;

        }

        public void setNewSelection(int position, boolean value) {

            mSelection.put(position, value);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public boolean isPositionChecked(int position) {
            Boolean result = mSelection.get(position);
            return result == null ? false : result;
        }

        public Set<Integer> getCurrentCheckedPosition() {
            return mSelection.keySet();
        }

        public void removeSelection(int position) {
            mSelection.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void clearSelection() {
            mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void selectAll() {

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                setNewSelection(i, true);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void inverseSel(){

            // Get the checked positions
            Set<Integer> selectedItems = mSelection.keySet();

            ArrayList<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> invSelected = new ArrayList<>();

            // Get the selected items
            for(int i: selectedItems){
                selected.add(i);
            }

            //Inverse the selection
            for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){

                int flag = 1;
                for(int j = 0; j<selected.size(); j++){

                    if(i == selected.get(j)){
                        flag = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(flag == 1)
                    invSelected.add(i);

            }

            mSelection.clear();

            for(int i: invSelected){
                mSelection.put(i, true);
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

}
```

Note - I didn't paste all the methods in the class, as they are not in context with this question and are very long.

**My Result**

This method inverses the selection correctly. But the problem is that the subtitle is not correct and when I try selecting selecting/deselecting other items, they don;t work as expected.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I did'nt understand your problem " subtitle is not correct and when I try selecting selecting/deselecting other items, they don;t work as expected." What does it mean?

Comment: After choosing the inverse option, the subtitle shows wrong number of items. And if I continue selecting or deselecting more items, its wrong again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with the following method for inverting the selections.

```
public void inverseSel() {
        // Get the checked positions
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            setNewSelection(i, !isPositionChecked(i));
        }
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: No it is absolutely not working. Just selecting all the items.

Comment: But all the values in the HashMap are getting inverted right?

Comment: Yes, seems so. But its not working. That's why I uses mSelection.clear() in my solution posted.